# Random colour changing with cell Interior.Color

Tags: vba, excel

I cobbled something simple together to see what would happen, and of course I broke excel.

```
Sub colourChange()

    Dim r As Byte, g As Byte, b As Byte

    On Error Resume Next

    For l = 0 To 50
        For j = 1 To 22
            For k = 1 To 66
                r = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 255)
                g = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 255)
                b = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 255)
                Cells(j, k).Interior.Color = RGB(r, g, b)
            Next k
        Next j
        Application.Wait Now + #12:00:03 AM#
    Next l

End Sub
```

It starts well, and then beings to slow down to a virtual standstill, eventually even producing the Too many different cell formats error.

Is there any way I can speed it up and stop the errors? I looked it up, excel is supposed to support 4000 different cell formats, and I shouldn't be hitting even half of that! Is it remembering the previous ones or something? What's going on here?

Comment: No idea. It's not remember previous formats for sure. Running this on an empty workbook (Excel 2016) works just fine with memory usage stable. No errors or anything.

Comment: Why are you using `Wait`?

Comment: Remove the `wait` and rerun

Comment: I wanted to have the macro run, and then repeat after a short delay, but I understand wait doesn't work exactly like that?

Comment: works fine on my computer

Answer (score 2):

I think for l= 0 to 50 not needed. 
And **Application.ScreenUpdating = False**  setting is help to practice faster.
And I guess Excel has a limit of total number of interior colors.

```
Sub colourChange()

    Dim r As Byte, g As Byte, b As Byte
    Dim vR(), n As Integer
    'Cells.Clear
    n = 3000
    ReDim vR(1 To n)
    For i = 1 To n
        r = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 255)
        g = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 255)
        b = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 255)
        vR(i) = RGB(r, g, b)
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For j = 1 To 500
            For k = 1 To 100
                Cells(j, k).Interior.Color = vR(WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, n))

            Next k
        Next j
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Other way,   first practice sub getColor()(first one time only) and then
practice colourchang() .

```
Public vR()
Public n As Integer
Sub getColor()
    Dim r As Byte, g As Byte, b As Byte
    Dim i As Integer
    'Cells.Clear
    n = 3000
    ReDim vR(1 To n)
    For i = 1 To n
        r = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 255)
        g = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 255)
        b = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 255)
        vR(i) = RGB(r, g, b)
    Next i

End Sub
Sub colourChange()
    Dim j As Integer, k As Integer, m As Integer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For j = 1 To 500
            For k = 1 To 100
                m = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, n)
                Cells(j, k).Interior.Color = vR(m)
            Next k
        Next j
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: this seems to work pretty good! but after I run it several times, it still produces this same error:

Run-time error '1004': Too many different cell formats.

Comment: There is limit of cell formats. Please  change n to 500 or less than 500. But I don't know the specific limit.

Comment: hmm I get a new error now, it is getting stuck on this like:
`Cells(j, k).Interior.Color = vR(WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, n))`

the error is....
`Run-time error 1004: Unable to get the interior property of the Range class`

I suspect it amounts to the same thing

Comment: @HotSauceCoconuts:  It is need, limit the cell foramats.  I add my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It works well for me. Be aware of that you are using `Wait` function, which causes 3 seconds delay of every "frame" :) The way to speed it up is to reduce the delay from 3 seconds to 1 second :)

But then the colors won't be changing that much, since random numbers generator is based on system time, and it will change less if we reduce the delay.

You could also use function `Rnd()` and multiply it by 256 instead of using worksheet function. But I am not sure, that it will affect the duration of the execution significantly.

Comment: Rnd() * 256 will execute faster indeed (since you do not have to access the `WorksheetFunction` object every time), although it's rather negligible.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks for clarification.